# Why all the reduce tasks are ending up in a single machine?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, load-balancing

I wrote a relatively simple map-reduce program in Hadoop platform (cloudera distribution). Each Map & Reduce write some diagnostic information to standard ouput besides the regular map-reduce tasks.

However when I'm looking at these log files, I found that Map tasks are relatively evenly distributed among the nodes (I have 8 nodes). But the reduce task standard output log can only be found in one single machine.

I guess, that means all the reduce tasks ended up executing in a single machine and that's  problematic and confusing.

Does anybody have any idea what's happening here ? Is it configuration problem ?
How can I make the reduce jobs also distribute evenly ?

Comment: Are the mappers generating multiple keys in the k-v pair?  If by chance that is a single key then there will be only one reducer.  If that is not the case then likely a config problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the output from your mappers all have the same key they will be put into a single reducer.

If your job has multiple reducers, but they all queue up on a single machine, then you have a configuration issue.

Use the web interface (`http://MACHINE_NAME:50030`) to monitor the job and see the reducers it has as well as what machines are running them. There is other information that can be drilled into that will provide information that should be helpful in figuring out the issue.

Couple questions about your configuration:

- How many reducers are running for the job?
- How many reducers are available on each node?
- Is the node running the reducer better
  hardware than the other nodes?

Comment: 1) 7 Reducers are running healthy. 2) how to check this one ? 3) all the reducers have the exact same hardware and software configuration.

Comment: I looked at the execution log from the web interface. It has multiple reduce tasks, but all the reduce tasks somehow running on a single machine.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Each node has 8 cores. So hadoop gonna fill up 8 tasks on this machine and move to the next. If I set the reducer count to a higher number (ex: 32), then it'll assign jobs to multiple nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop decides which Reducer will process which output keys by the use of a [Partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html)
If you are only outputting a few keys and want an even distribution across your reducers, you may be better off implementing a custom Partitioner for your output data. eg

```
public class MyCustomPartitioner extends Partitioner<KEY, VALUE>
{
    public int getPartition(KEY key, VALUE value, int numPartitions) {
            // do something based on the key or value to determine which 
            // partition we want it to go to.
    }
}
```

You can then set this custom partitioner in the job configuration with

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "My Job Name");
job.setPartitionerClass(MyCustomPartitioner.class);
```

You can also implement the Configurable interface in your custom Partitioner if you want to do any further configuration based on job settings.
Also, check that you haven't set the number of reduce tasks to 1 anywhere in the configuration (look for "mapred.reduce.tasks"), or in code, eg

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```